# Docker Error: push is already in progress

Tags: docker

I'm trying to push a container that was interrupted previously by a network drop out. But I get this error:

```
Error: push rimian/ruby-node-npm is already in progress
```

But when I run `docker ps` I don't see anything running.

What shall I do?

Answer (score 23):

Restart the docker service on which you are running the docker.
With ubuntu:

```
sudo service docker restart
```

Comment: for mac os x users, it's `boot2docker restart`. more discussions: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/5113#issuecomment-58881167

Comment: for mac osx with docker-machine it's "docker-machine restart default"

Comment: Just in case someone doesn't know how to restart the docker daemon/service on Debian/Ubuntu/etc. where systemd is in use: `sudo systemctl restart docker`.

Answer (score 15):

Just wait.

I had this once, too, and the problem is that the push is still running in the background, hence you can't do another one.

So just wait, and the problem will disappear automatically after some time.

The fact that you do not see anything running with `docker ps` is that this command only shows docker containers, not internal docker processes. And pushing an image is not run by a container.

Comment: I restarted boot2docker and this seemed to fix it.

Comment: Of course, because you shut down the server the hard way ;-).

Comment: Yes, it's definitely still running in the background and evenutally finishes. Is there any way to "reconnect" the status to see how long the push will take?